# Visual Studio Code's console used to open and close immediately, now it won't open at all

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, console

I'm a beginner starting with C#, and I'm not really sure what to do. I've exhausted all the methods I can come up with (reinstalling vscode, ctrl + f5, etc.) And I'm certain it's not a problem with my code, as it runs fine when I tried it on an online compiler.
I'm sure that this will be just the first of many questions I'll ask on Stack Overflow. So thank you for all the help!

Here are some of the things I did:

1. Ran the project using an online compiler (the code worked there)
2. Completely reinstall VS Code (deleted "Code" in %appdata%) and .NET
3. Used Console.ReadKey(); at the end,
4. Ran without debugging (CTRL + F5)
5. Disabled/Uninstalled the extensions
6. Updated .NET
7. Set the integrated terminal to "Powershell"
8. Disabled Debug › Console: Close On End

Answer (score 0):

Try View > Terminal. The shortcut for it is Ctrl + `. That should open and close the terminal window at will.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, thank you though!